# Timeout issue with PostgreSQL and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, postgresql, npgsql

When I try to query a PostgreSQL database through `EntityFramework6.Npgsql` with the following code:

```
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
   var res = (from b in context.mytable select new { b.Name, b.Age }); 
   foreach (var row in res)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(row.Name + " - " + row.Age);
   }
}
```

I get a timeout exception after fetching few lines with the following error:

> [Npgsql.NpgsqlException] : {"57014: canceling statement due to
>   statement timeout"}
>
> Message: 57014: canceling statement due to
>   statement timeout

When I execute the same operation while fetching all the data to a List, the code works fine:

```
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
   var res = (from b in context.mytable select new { b.Name, b.Age }).ToList(); 
   foreach (var row in res)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(row.Name + " - " + row.Age);
   }
}
```

I suspect that it is related to the way PostgreSQL manages its connection pool but I don't know how I could handle it correctly through Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably related to the way Npgsql manages timeouts. In current versions, Npgsql sets the PostgreSQL `statement_timeout` variable which causes PostgreSQL to generate a timeout error after some time. The problem with this method is that `statement_timeout` is unreliable for this: it includes network time, client processing time, etc. so too much time spent on the client could make the server generate the error.

In your example, calling ToList() means that you immediately download all results, rather than iterate over them little by little. I do admit it's strange that such short client processing (i.e. `Console.WriteLine`) could introduce a delay sufficient to trigger a backend timeout (what is the command timeout set to?).

Note that the next major version of Npgsql will remove backend timeouts entirely because of the unreliable nature of `statement_timeout` - see https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/689. For now you can manually disable backend timeouts by setting the `Backend Timeouts` connection string parameter to false (see http://www.npgsql.org/doc/3.0/connection-string-parameters.html).

Comment: I am not setting the command timeout, just using the default values

Comment: OK, it's conceivable that the `Console.WriteLine`s are adding enough delay so as to trigger this behavior... I'd recommend disabling backend timeouts in general.

Comment: By adding Backend Timeouts=false to the connection string, it works perfectly.

Comment: Link is broken. It should be http://www.npgsql.org/doc/3.1/connection-string-parameters.html but since the edit is less than 6 chars it won't let me do it.

Comment: The link posted by Owen is also dead now... The one that currently works is http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html.

Comment: In 2021, you need to add `Command Timeout=0`